# An unknown error has occurred in Cloud Function: GCP Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, runtime-error

Log Viewer
[image: Log Viewer]

Unknown Error Image
[image: Unknown Error]

I am running into an Unknown Error while executing a Cloud Function in GCP (Python). 
Steps:

1. Running Cloud Function to retrieve the data from BigQuery DataStore and save the CSV file in GCP Storage.
2. Running Cloud Function to retrieve the data from BigQuery DataStore and save the CSV file in GCP Storage.
3. Running Cloud Function to retrieve the data from BigQuery DataStore and save the CSV file in GCP Storage.
4. It is executing successfully and files are stored in Storage. If you view the Logs it is showing Finished with Status Code 200 (attached is the log view image), which is success code.
5. However, in the end we are getting Unknown Error with some tracking number as per the attached screen shot.
6. Have anyone seen this earlier and suggestions for resolution.

Comment: The dialog appears when u click somewhere.. r u clicking somewhere and then receiving error?

Comment: It appears without clicking anywhere. As per my response below this is related to Cloud Function Test UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on my follow up with Google Support, it seems this is related to Cloud Console itself.

The error message which we are experiencing is related to Cloud Function's Tester UI timing out. Currently it is set to 1 minute maximum even when Cloud Function itself has a timeout window different (between 1 min to 9mins maximum). So if we are using the CF UI Testing (Test Function option in CF), it will time out in 1 min, even though CF will successfully execute (Success Code 200 in view log)

As per the Google Support, CF Product team is working on delivering a more descriptive message (for 1 min UT Testing timeout) instead of this error. Also they are not sure if CF’s Product Team is going to set the CF’s testing UI timeout same as the CF timeout. No ETA yet.

So we will running our CF differently and not using CF UI Console for testing.