# Unknown error has occurred in Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

First, it looks like this thread but it is not: [An unknown error has occurred in Cloud Function: GCP Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61284352/an-unknown-error-has-occurred-in-cloud-function-gcp-python)

I deployed a couple of times Cloud Functions and they are still working fine. Nevertheless, since last week, following the same procedure I can deploy correctly, but testing them I get the error "An unknown error has occurred in Cloud Functions. The attempted action failed. Please try again, send feedback".

- In remote the script works perfectly and writes in Cloud Storage.
- My Cloud Function is a zip with a python script, loading a csv in Cloud Storage.
- The csv weights 160kB, the python script 5kB. So I used 128MiB of memory allocated.
- The execution time is 38 secs, almost half of the default timeout.
- It is configured to allow just traffic within the project.
- Env variables are not the problem

It's triggered by pub/sub and what I want is to schedule it when I can make it work.

I'm quite puzzled. I have such a lack of ideas right now that I started to think everything works fine but the Google testing method is what is fails... Nevertheless when I run the pub/sub topic in Cloud Scheduler it launches the error log without much info [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb1OX.png). By any chance anyone had the same problem?

Thanks

Comment: Usually that error means an unhandled exception. Did you change any dependencies (pip installed something) and then forgot to update the requirements.txt file?

Comment: Can you share a minimal function with us that reproduces this?

Comment: Hey @GabeWeiss, the requirements and txt is stable

Comment: Hi @DustinIngram, this is the script. of course the Cloud Function is executing "main" https://github.com/albertovpd/automated_etl_google_cloud-social_dashboard/tree/master/cloud_function 

I'm using credentials with the right roles... But from reddit I've been told that maybe it can be the service account user role, I need to check it.

Anyway, I'm using in the CF the service account I created to get credentials and work in remote... Maybe if I use the app service account and modify its permissions... I need to work on it.

Thanks to you both

Comment: Is it possible the files aren't executable? (pytrends_request.py, etc) and so calling them directly without the Python interpreter (e.g. `python pytrends_requests.py`) is failing?

Comment: Hi @GabeWeiss, the funny thing is that I got in my job some scripts with the very same structure running fine on schedule, and the scripts work fine in remote.

When configuring the CF, you must select Service Account*. I think it has to be with that... Nevertheless, there I selected the Service Account for which I created the json credentials, the app engine service account... All posibilities, I starting modifying roles of all of them just to check it out... With the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### *Answer of myself from the past*:

- Finally "solved". I'm a processing a csv in the CF of 160kB, in my computer the execution time lasts 38 seconds. For some reason in the CF I need 512MB of Allocated Memory and a timeout larger than 60 secs.

###### *Answer of myself from a closest past*:

- Don't test a CF using the *test* button, because sometimes it takes more than the max available timeout to finish, hence you'll get errors.

If you want to test it easily

- Write *prints* after milestones in your code to check how the script is evolving.
- Use the **logs** interface. The prints will be displayed there ;)
- Also, logs show valuable info (sometimes even readable).
- Also, if you're sending for example, to buckets, check them after the CF is finished, maybe you get a surprise.

To sum up, don't believe blindly in the *testing button*.

###### *Answer of myself from the present* (already regretting the prints thing):

- There are nice python libraries to check logs, don't print stuff for that (if you have time).